# How do I find a points distance from a rectangle that is defined by half-width/height, two vectors and a middle point?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, rectangles

So I've been trying to figure this out for days and I feel like I'm close but I think the solution I came up with only works for a rect that is aligned to a vertical/horizontal axis because the rect my program drew was not rotated.

Also, I'm not sure how the rotation is being represented: There are two directional vectors given along with the half-width/height and middle point of the rectangle, are these supposed to represent the rotation of the rectangle? If so, how do I determine the rotation from these two vectors, dot product?

Comment: Your rectangle is over-specified. The center, a vector from the center to the middle of a side and the half-side are enough.

Comment: You you need the distance to the outline of the rectangle or to the whole area of the rectangle ?

Comment: I believe it needs to be the whole area

Answer (score 0):

First translate the point and the rectangle to center the rectangle on the origin, and counter-rotate to make the rectangle axis-aligned. (Moving a corner to the origin also works.)

The extended sides of the rectangle define nine regions of the plane, and depending on the region the closest point is either on the nearest edge or is the nearest corner.

These are elementary computations.

[image]

Comment: I suppose the point will also be translated by the same amount? Or is aligning the rectangle a means of giving the rect and point a shared origin/coordinate system...?

Comment: @BenArceneaux: didn't I write " translate the point and the rectangle" ? Actually, this step is optionnal, you can just counter-rotate.